# Winform flat button disabled appearance

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, button

Problem is that my flat button with background image on it has same appearance enabled and disabled.
Is there any way of changing default template of disabled buttons or i need to do it manually after disabling my button and then also when setting it back to enabled?

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: So you probably made the image too big and can't see the dark-gray background anymore. Consider using the EnabledChanged event and the ToolStripRenderer.CreateDisabledImage() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't set second image which will be shown as background image of  your button automatically when you disable that button, it without coding. There is no similar property.